# running event scheeduler phpmyadmin on raspberry pi 2

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

so i am a beginner using raspberry pi2, i'm trying to run this sql query on phpmyadmin on my raspberry, but there is no export file in my folder, but i can run this query on my windows laptop, so whats wrong?
please help  me

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MINUTE
STARTS '2016-07-08 17:50:00'
DO 
BEGIN
SET @TS = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'-%Y-%m-%d_%H.%i');

SET @FOLDER = 'c:/xampp/flogger/';
SET @PREFIX = 'datafrekuensi';
SET @EXT    = '.csv';

SET @CMD = CONCAT("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '",@FOLDER,@PREFIX,@TS,@EXT,
    "' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '""' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '""'",
    "  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM frequency WHERE Time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 Minute);");

PREPARE statement FROM @CMD;

EXECUTE statement;
END

EXECUTE statement;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Have you checked the MySQL error log to see if the event is firing & if any errors are reported.

Comment: @PaulF there are no error with the query

Comment: If this is your actual code with the path `c:/xampp/flogger/` and your rasberry pi runs linux distribution, then the path is most likely wrong.